# Notebook that supports 32 GB RAM

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm searching for a notebook that supports 32 GB RAM. You can recommend one or multiple (all notebooks with 32 GB RAM support you know) devices.

I have already tried to find something by myself, but with Google I only found a small number of very expensive gaming notebooks or mobile workstations.

**Requirements:**

- Supports 32 GB RAM. Bonus points if it's pre-installed.
- Between 600 and 1300 Dollar/ Euros.
- Sufficient processing power to run virtualisation stuff: VMs, servers, cloud computing software.

**Not required:**

- Any more than a basic graphics card.

I don't *mind* having anything that's *Not Required*, but it's non-essential and must meet the requirements first.

**Update:**

I want a new goods notebook, with two years manufacturer warranty!

Comment: The best thing you can do is to visit http://ark.intel.com/#@Processors. Choose "mobile" and use the filter to find those which have max memory size = 32 GB. Newer Thinkpads (W series) can support 4 slots x 8 GB of memory. I guess that buying second-hand DELL or HP can be also an option. It's all about processor, number of slots and memory type. Company isn't that important.

Answer (score 2):

I would reccomend buying a laptop from digital storm. You can customize your laptop to your likings and price range. Most of the laptops they have are themed towards gaming but they can be used to run vms and all that stuff. You can customize your computer so if you do not want a graphics card you do not have to have a graphics card. Most of there laptops support 32gb of ram and you can have several different options for CPUs so you can get one that fits your performance and price needs. Everything also comes pre installed. I believe this should meet all of your requirements. Digital storm does only have a one year warranty but some of the parts may have a longer warranty and digital storm will replace the parts within 3 years of the Purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Many mobile Workstations using i5/i7 CPUs from DELL/HP/THINKPAD or other vendors can meet your requirements. Usually they provide 4 memory slots and of course, they support virtualisation features, but not suitable for server-like heavy computing works.

Almost all the i5/i7 CPU with 4 cores can support 32GB or more memory(like the early i7-4770hq\i7-2670QM), some 5/6th generation i5/i7 CPUs with 2 cores also support 32GB memory(like i5-6260U\i7-6500U).
And you can use this site:http://ark.intel.com/#@Processors to check if a CPU can support 32GB memory.

Here are some recommended series: DELL precision M4800/4700/4600, THINKPAD w530/540 ,HP ZBOOK14/17/8470P/8570P. You can find some refurnished/second-hand ones(often with 8 memory) on ebay or amazon warehouse , usually it will cost you around 1000 USD/EURO including additional memories.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but all your recommend devices are not new goods, when they cost arround 1000 Euro/ Dollar. I've checked out all models and found that they still cost acround 2000 or more if its new!

Answer (score 1):

Your price criteria is quite demanding (what you're looking for tends to be 1800+ Euro), but the **short quick answer** would be http://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/notebooks/defianceII-15/

Specs:
*6th Gen Intel i7 Quad Core 8 Thread 6700HQ, has Vt-x and VT-d

GeForce GTX 965M 2GB Graphics Card

32GB (4x8GB) 2133MHz DDR4 Memory installed-supports 64GB

3 year standard warranty*

15.6" Matte Full HD IPS
Backlit Keyboard (very very nice)
4 x USB 3.0
HDMI Output Connection & Mini Display Port
Intel AC8260 (867Mbps) M.2 Wireless and Bluetooth
Fingerprint Scanner

with a 500GB HDD (36 Euro) and Windows 10 (106 Euro) and delivery to EU (26 Euro-they do deliver elsewhere) comes to a total of ***1334 Euro***. Using their configurator you could remove Windows 10 for a Linux distro and replace the HDD with a 240GB SSD for ***1284 Euro.*** If you need Windows you could install that later as a host OS or a VM. At the same time It's a very good graphics card and to utilize it fully with Direct X (to play some games too), maybe buy a standalone Windows license. As opposed to an OEM Windows license, which only allows you to use Windows on *that* machine (hard install or VM), you can easily move Windows to any another machine (physical or VM). Highly recommended to buy the HDD caddy too.

**If you know you need 32GB this is the system I would recommend**, as it exceeds both your required (2133 MHz DDR4 RAM, I assume you would have been happy with 1600MHz DDR3L) and not required (gaming graphics) specs. It'll easily destroy any common VM setup. Should handle any personal cloud computing stuff, obviously depends on the stuff. I'd leave server stuff to servers, again depending on end use, a small server shouldn't be too much of a problem.

**Another (possibly cheaper) Option:**
You would want an i7 with virtualization support i.e VT-x (either 5th or 6th Gen) but are you sure you *really need 32GB*? You could get a dual core, four threaded i7 machine with 8-16GB with at least 2 RAM slots and pretty good graphics for 700-1000 Euro. 16GB is a lot of memory for running VMs. For example you could buy a 16GB machine easily for under 1000 Euro and try it. If you actually do need more RAM you could upgrade and you wouldn't necessarily be limited by 2 RAM slots (4 slots is obviously preferable). SODIMM RAM on laptops is usually limited to 8GB due to specification, however a clever company called [Intelligent Memory](http://www.intelligentmemory.com/dram-modules/ddr3-so-dimm/#collapseA1) has managed to stack a massive 16GB DDR3 on a single stick! So even with only 2 RAM slots you can reach 32GB.You can get them at [amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=M&url=me=A3R9S9CHC6ARGB&field-keywords) all you need is any 5th (Intelligent Memory) or 6th (PACCOM) Intel CPU, which you'll already have.

Answer (score 0):

[Lenovo ThinkPad T460](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t460/#SYSTEM) supports up to 32GB RAM and can be ordered in such configuration. Price tag for most most basic config with 32GB RAM is $1200.